# how to add a textBox and a TextField to a form in j2me

Tags: java-me

i want to display both TextBox and TextField on the screen at a time but i am unable to add TextBox to form. is there any way to display both of them at a time. that is textBox at the top and TextField below it. plz help me. i will be pleased if any code is given

thank u in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TextBox` is a `Screen`, not an `Item`, therefore you cannot add it to a `Form`, and there is no way to display both of these things on screen at once.

If you want to display some additional text on screen while a `TextBox` is active, you can use its title (via [`setTitle()`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextBox.html#setTitle%28java.lang.String%29)), or you could scroll it across the top using [`setTicker()`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextBox.html#setTicker%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Ticker%29).

Comment: i am getting your answer but how to use ticker.actually i want to design the screen such that user types in a data when he press the "send" command it should be displayed in the area above the field which we have entered just like gtalk (visually)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you must write you own `TextBox` component. It must extend `Canvas`. And you must paint it yourself, using `drawLine`, `drawString`.